# Grover meets Anyone - feasibility

Tags: grovers-algorithm, oracles, amplitude-amplification, simons-algorithm

Recently, a variety of algorithms have been proposed to combine Grover algorithm with other quantum algorithms.

As an example, given a function $f: \{0, 1\}^n\mapsto \{0,1\}$, the Grover meet Simon algorithm is used to find the length-$m$ bitstring $v$ for which $f$ becomes cyclic with period $s$ (that is, $f(v, x) = f(v, x+s)$).
In this algorithm, Grover's oracle is therefore replaced by Simon's procedure.

I have some troubles in understanding this setting, though, or maybe in analyzing it. When I use Simon's algorithm, I create a superposition over all the input domain of $f$ (that is, all the $2^n$ values of $x$); on the other hand, Grover's create a superposition over all the possible bitstrings possibly leading to a cyclic function (that is, all the $2^m$ values of $v$).

At this point, since Simon's algorithm has a linear running time, the algorithm assumes that the running time is $O(m\sqrt{2^n})$ (that is, mostly one of Grover's algorithm).

My questions below.

1. When I use Simon's algorithm as an inner procedure, doesn't the whole search space increase from $2^n$ to $2^{n+m}$? Why doesn't it translate into an increased number of iterations?
2. In general, what is the correct way to analyze inner searches of Grover's algorithm?

Comment: I guess you are talking in the context of FX construction.  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2017/106240174/106240174.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiD8YT17tKEAxVHa2wGHbuuDSwQFnoECBkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3ZzSw2b4zeExF5UoiTGqjJ

Comment: @ManishKumar yes, this is the context in which I read it, but my question I guess can be generalized to other approaches as well.